# Java process CPU usage threshold on UNIX

Tags: java, unix, cpu-usage

A java process running inside UNIX server is usually showing CPU % usage between 10% to 20%.

But, sometimes it jumps to 60% for a second and then immediately come down to 40%, then 20% and so on.

Is this CPU utilization dangerous? What is the usual threshold of CPU percent usage?

Please note, I am running `top -c` command with <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> (to turn off IRIS mode) to monitor the CPU usage.

Comment: May I know the reasons for down vote? So that I can improve the question.

Comment: I guess because this question is off topic at SO.

Comment: I was not aware of it. Is it possible to move it to correct forum, I think unix.stackexchange.

Comment: You can flag your own answer and ask a moderator to migrate it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this CPU utilization dangerous?

Not at all. Having a CPU load randomly reaching 60% for one second while moving from 20% to 40% otherwise is a pretty common situation.

> What is the usual threshold of CPU percent usage?

There is no usual threshold. The CPU is designed to be used. There certainly are use cases where having all cores stuck at 100% for hours is expected, for example CPU bound batches. You are talking about a Unix server and these machines are built to support continuous load. Even if you use a consumer grade machine, or even a laptop, modern CPUs have internal protection against overheating so it should never be "dangerous". After reaching a first threshold the CPU will reduce its clock speed (thermal throttling) and if not sufficient, it will turn itself off. The main risk is for your ears if the server is not in a dedicated room as the fans might became noisy by running full speed to cool down your hardware.

In any case, with spurious 60% CPU load, you are far from this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Dangerous?  Not normally.  But if your server has a poor heat sink, then it may tend to heat up when all cores are in full use.  The tool `sensors` displays data from various internal temperature sensors and is a better indicator of overheating.

The CPU usage indication is generally 100%, or on some systems, 100% times the number of cores, so that a 4 core server may show up to 400%.

If a process running on one core has no competition for the CPU from other processes, and does not wait (e.g., for disk, for user input) then it will typically run at 100%.

Example `sensors` output (no danger):

```
sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +55.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +53.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +53.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +52.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +55.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Comment: I think lm-sensors are not available by default, one needs to install that on his/her own(at least in Linux/Redhat), don't know about Unix.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Ubuntu here, don't know about availability of this tool generally, either.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I've also heard that modern hardware will slow down or shut itself down if heat becomes an issue.  Never pushed hard enough to find out, and usually buy aftermarket heatsinks.

Comment: I have also heard the same about modern hardwares, never have got the chance to verify it practically. Nice answer though. +1,:)